# How to get the number of elements on the data stack?

Tags: stack, factor-lang

Is there a possibility to get the count of elements on the stack?

For example if the stack looks like this:

```
--- Data stack:
1
1
1
```

the result should be `3`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
datastack length
```

Comment: `get-datastack length` in the latest version.